# Problems with LocalDate in Hibernate 5.2.10 Final and MySQL 5.7

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, localdate

I's using Java8, Hibernate 5.2.10Final and MySQL 5.7 in my project. But I got some problems while using `java.time.LocalDate` .
There are two entity classes:

TradeDay.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY__TRADE_DAY")
public class TradeDay {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "TRADE_DAY_DATE")
    private LocalDate date;

    ........

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Transaction.class, mappedBy = "tradeDay", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
    private Set<Transaction> transactionSet=new LinkedHashSet<>();

    ........
}
```

And Transaction.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY__TRANSACTION")
public class Transaction {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "increase")
    @TableGenerator(name = "increase", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "TRANSACTION_INDEX")
    private int index;

    ........

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = TradeDay.class,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TRADE_DAY_DATE")
    private TradeDay tradeDay;

    ........
}
```

Then the problems I've run into:

1.When I use `LocalDate` as a key in HQL, the final value in SQL will be the previous date. For example:

```
@Override
public List<Transaction> getTransactionList(LocalDate date) {
    Session session = HibernateSessionManager.getCurrentSession();
    Query<Transaction> query = session.createQuery("from Transaction t where t.date=? order by t.index asc", Transaction.class);
    query.setParameter(0,date);
    return query.list();
}
```

ps: the `t.date` is equal to `transaction.getTradeDay().getDate()`.

I use this code to search in database. However when I give a parameter like `2010-12-18`, the dates of results are all `2010-12-17`.

2.I use `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)` to make sure that when I invoke method `transactionSet.size()` hibernate will only excute a "count" SQL. It actually worked but when I iterate it there's nothing in the set.

Test code:

```
......//Before, get a TradeDay entity

Set<Transaction> transactionSet=tradeDay.getTransactionSet();
System.out.println(tradeDay.getDate()+" complete with "+transactionSet.size()+" records.");
for(Transaction transaction:transactionSet){
    System.out.println(transaction.getIndex());
}

//Impl of `getTransactionList` is the code above
List<Transaction> transactionList=DAOManager.getTransactionDAO().getTransactionList(tradeDay.getDate());
System.out.println(tradeDay.getDate()+" complete with "+transactionList.size()+" records.");
for(Transaction transaction:transactionList){
    System.out.println(transaction.getIndex());
}
```

Output like this:

```
//Just a count SQL because of @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
Hibernate: select count(TRANSACTION_INDEX) from ENTITY__TRANSACTION where TRADE_DAY_DATE =?

//count SQL got 4 result
1990-12-20 complete with 4 records.

//Iterate set, real SQL
Hibernate: select ...... from ENTITY__TRANSACTION transactio0_ where transactio0_.TRADE_DAY_DATE=?

//No index output???

//SQL by getTransactionList
Hibernate: select ...... from ENTITY__TRANSACTION transactio0_ where transactio0_.TRANSACTION_DATE=? order by transactio0_.TRANSACTION_INDEX asc

//Got 4 result too
1990-12-20 complete with 4 records.

//Success print the index
5535748
5882738
5925376
6165413
```

How do I solve these problems? Thanks for any help.

Comment: This made a lot of noise recently when someone had a different timezone on their database than on the other server. There are discussions and proposed solutions https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11396 and https://vladmihalcea.com/2017/03/14/how-to-store-date-time-and-timestamps-in-utc-time-zone-with-jdbc-and-hibernate/ where they tell you which properties to change to your JDBC url and the Hibernate configuration.

Comment: What is MySql driver version that you are using?

Comment: Also, can you your connection configuration, mainly the `URL` property?

Comment: @fujy Driver version is mysql-connector-java 6.0.6 and the  `connection.url`  is  `jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.122/quant`

Comment: @coladict Appreciate for your help. Actually my client and server have the same timezone(Asia/Shanghai). I tried to use the property  `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone` but the result had no difference.

Comment: @王立巍, can you try these two SQL queries in your SQL console `SELECT @global.time_zone;` and `SELECT @@session.time_zone;` and check if they have the same result if you initialized a new Date() object in your java application?

Comment: @fujy, I didn’t understand the last bit since a `Date` does not have a time zone in it. You may use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` to get your JVM’s default time zone.